# How to make object instance a hash key in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have a class  Foo  with a few member variables. When all values in two instances of the class are equal I want the objects to be 'equal'.  I'd then like these objects to be keys in my hash.  When I currently try this, the hash treats each instance as unequal.

```
h = {}
f1 = Foo.new(a,b)
f2 = Foo.new(a,b)
```

f1 and f2 should be equal at this point.

```
h[f1] = 7
h[f2] = 8
puts h[f1]
```

should print 8

Answer (score 64, accepted):

See [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html):

> Hash uses `key.eql?` to test keys for
> equality. If you need to use instances
> of your own classes as keys in a `Hash`,
> it is recommended that you define both
> the `eql?` and `hash` methods. The hash
> method must have the property that
> `a.eql?(b)` implies `a.hash == b.hash`.

The `eql?` method is easy to implement: `return true` if all member variables are the same. For the `hash` method, use `[@data1, @data2].hash` as Marc-Andre suggests in the comments.

Comment: Good, except that returned hash should be a fixnum, so better use exclusive or instead of sum (which could overflow to a bignum). Alternatively, use `Array#hash`, like `[@data1, @data2].hash`, say.

Comment: Good point. Adding individual hashes together also has the danger that the same sum could result from different individual hashes (3 + 2 = 5 and 1 + 4 = 5). Using Array#hash as Marc-Andre suggests would make the solution more complete.

Comment: They are not the same object, but they still can be defined as 'equal'. For example, two strings with the same content could not be the same object, still you can use them as keys.

Comment: Thanks everyone for commenting. To answer some of the comments... yes, i'm aware I have two instances of the same object, but i consider them 'equal' because both contain the same two params (a & b).

As far as the .hash and.eql? methods.  Do I need both, or just one?  I"ll play around with this and post back the code when I get it working.

Comment: I would strongly recommend implementing both hash and eql?. BTW, if this works for you, can you accept this answer?  Thx

Comment: This answer has a lot of comments on why it's wrong for being such a highly visible (on google) answer with so many upvotes and accepted.

Comment: Marc-André is right that hash must return a Fixnum, but he doesn't say why. The answer is: If it returns a value that's immutable but not a Fixnum, uniq will choke on it.

Answer (score -3):

Add a method called 'hash' to your class:

```
class Foo
  def hash
    return whatever_munge_of_instance_variables_you_like
  end
end
```

This will work the way you requested and won't generate different hash keys for different, but identical, objects.

Comment: You should also define the eql? method in a way that's consistent with the hash method. Also, the hash method must return a Fixnum, or it will break uniq.