# How do I force the same hash value for different object instantiations in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using RoR 5.0.1.  I have a model that is not persisted to a database.  It has two fields

```
first_field
second_field
```

How do I force different instantiations of the object in which its fields have the same value to have the same hash value?  Right now it seems each unique creation of an object has a different hash value, even if the individual attributes have the same values .  So if I create two different objects

```
o1 = MyObject.new({:first_field => 5, :second_field => "a"})

o2 = MyObject.new({:first_field => 5, :second_field => "a"})
```

I'd like them to have the same hash values even though they are different instantiations of the object.

Comment: You can overwrite `hash` method of `MyObject` (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-hash), but this will break so many things...

Comment: are you wanting them to be the same such that editing one modifies the other, or are you wanting `o1 == o2` to be `true`?

Comment: @MichaelGorman, If h = {}, then I want h[o1] to yield the same result as h[o2].

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328685/how-to-make-object-instance-a-hash-key-in-ruby) should be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're looking for isn't entirely clear from your question. However, if you want (as Michael Gorman asks) the instances of `MyObject` to share the same `hash` instance (such that changes to the values `o1` are reflected in the values of `o2`), then you could do something like:

```
  class MyObject

    def initialize(hsh = {})
      @hsh = hsh
      hsh.each do |k,v|
        class_eval do

          # define the getter
          define_method(k) do 
            @hsh[k]
          end

          # define the setter
          define_method("#{k}=") do |val|
            @hsh[k] = val
          end

        end
      end
    end

  end
```

Then create a single instance of a `hash`:

```
  hsh = {first_field: 5, second_field: "a"}
```

And instantiate your two objects with this `hash`:

```
  o1 = MyObject.new(hsh)
  o2 = MyObject.new(hsh)
```

Both instances will have the same `first_field` value:

```
  2.3.1 :030 > o1.first_field
   => 5 
  2.3.1 :031 > o2.first_field
   => 5
```

And changes in `o1.first_field` will be reflected in `o2.first_field`:

```
  2.3.1 :033 > o1.first_field = 7
   => 7 
  2.3.1 :034 > o1.first_field
   => 7 
  2.3.1 :035 > o2.first_field
   => 7
```

Same with `second_field`:

```
  2.3.1 :037 > o1.second_field
   => "a" 
  2.3.1 :038 > o2.second_field
   => "a" 

  2.3.1 :040 > o1.second_field = "b"
   => "b" 
  2.3.1 :041 > o1.second_field
   => "b" 
  2.3.1 :042 > o2.second_field
   => "b"
```

Since the `setter` and `getter` are generated dynamically, you could do something like:

```
  hsh = {first_field: 5, second_field: "a", nth_field: {foo: :bar}}
  o1 = MyObject.new(hsh)
```

And `o1` will respond to `nth_field` without having to do any extra coding on `MyObject`:

```
  2.3.1 :048 > o1.nth_field
   => {:foo=>:bar}
```

Comment: To clarify what I want, from your example, if I set hsh[o1] = 3, then I want hash[o2] to produce 3, assuming o1.first_field == o2.first_field and o1.second_field == o2.second_field. DOes that make sense?

Comment: I assume you meant, "if I set *hash*[o1] = 3, then I want hash[o2] to produce 3". I'm still a little fuzzy on what you're exactly trying to do. But, it seems to me like you have requirements that are not well suited to `Hash`.